# To find the inverse of an implicit function

Tags: functions, numerical-methods, inverse

I have a function $t(f)$ here:

$t(f) = T(sin(2\pi f/B)/2\pi + f/B)  $ for $[-B/2 \le f \le B/2]$.
$B$ and $T$ are constants.

How to find the inverse of this function that is $f(t)$ using numerical methods.

Can you guide me.

Example parameters: $T = 100E-6,B = 2E6,t$ varies from -50E-6 to 50E-6.

Comment: Please check yor definition of $t(f).\;$  It currently does **not** depend on $f$ but on $t$.

Comment: @gammatester, corrected the definition.

Comment: Given $t$, solve for $f$ using Newton probably. If you want me to elaborate, give me some values of $t$ and the parameters $B,T$.

Comment: You could notice that setting $x=t/T$ and $y=f/B$ makes the problem nicer.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici. I have updated the question with example parameters.

Comment: I do not think that the values are important since we solved the problem in reduced coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in a comment, the problem is nicer setting $t=xT$ and $f=yB$. The equation becomes $$x=y+\frac{\sin (2 \pi  y)}{2 \pi }$$ with $[0 \le y \le \frac{1}{2} ]$ since changing $y$ to $-y$ changes $x$ to $-x$.

There no analytical way to express $y$ as a function of $x$ and numerical methods, such as Newton should be used. If $$f(y)=y+\frac{\sin (2 \pi  y)}{2 \pi }-x$$  the solution will be given by $$y_{n+1}=y_n-\frac{f(y_n)}{f'(y_n)}$$ with $$f'(y)=1+\cos (2 \pi  y)$$ The problem is to find a "good" starting point. What I do propose here is to approximate $$\sin(z)=a z(\pi-z)$$ where $a=\frac{120}{\pi ^5}$ has been obtained minimizing with respect to $a$ $$\int_0^\pi\Big(\sin(z)-a z(\pi-z)\Big)^2 dz$$  So, the approximate solution will be obtained solving $$y+\frac{120}{\pi ^4} y (1 -2   y)-x=0$$ The valid solution is given by $$y=\frac{1}{480} \left(120+\pi ^4-\sqrt{\left(120+\pi ^4\right)^2-960 \pi ^4 x}\right)$$ from which can start Newton iterations using this last value as $y_0$.

For illustration purposes, let us consider the case where $x=0.4$; so $y_0=0.246049$ and the successive iterates are $0.241019$, $0.241094$  which is the solution for six significant figures. If instead $x=0.1$ was used, $y_0=0.0472713$ and the successive iterates are $0.0504148$, $0.0504196$  which is the solution for six significant figures.

So, the numerical inversion seems to be simple, fast and robust.

This could be improved if we use the appoximation $$\sin(x) \simeq \frac{16 (\pi -x) x}{5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -x) x}$$ proposed by Mahabhaskariya of Bhaskara I, a seventh-century Indian mathematician. This would imply the resolution of a cubic equation in $y$ with only one real root; its analytic solution can be established using Cardano but its expression is too long and too complex to be reported here. For illustration, let us say that, for $x=0.4$, $y_0=0.241097$ and for $x=0.1$, $y_0=0.050312$ which are extremely close to the exact solutions.

To point out the accuracy of the method, the exact value $$\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}y dx= \frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\simeq 0.07434$$ while using the simplest approximation, the result is $$\frac{\pi^4(360-\pi^4)}{345600} \simeq 0.07401$$

In fact, the estimation looks to be so good that an higher order iterative method (Halley, Hoseholder,...) provides the solution immediately. For the same cases, increasing the order of the method give **after a single iteration** : $0.241019$, $0.241096$,$0.241094$,$0.241094$,$0.241094$ and $0.0504148$, $0.0504194$, $0.0504196$, $0.0504196$,$0.0504196$. So, one iteration of Householder method is sufficient and the process can be considered as analytical.